# which(x, arr.ind=T) in RCPP

Tags: rcpp

I couldn't find the cool `which(x,arr.ind=T)` feature in Rcpp or RcppArmadillo. So I decided to quickly code that up on my own.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::umat whicha(arma::mat matrix, int what ){
  arma::uvec outp1;
  int n  =   matrix.n_rows;
  outp1  =   find(matrix==what);
  int nf =   outp1.n_elem;
  arma::mat  out(nf,2);
  arma::vec  foo;
  arma::uvec foo2;
  foo = arma::conv_to<arma::colvec>::from(outp1) +1;  
  foo2 = arma::conv_to<arma::uvec>::from(foo);
  for(int i=0; i<nf; i++){
    out(i,0) = ( foo2(i) %n);
    out(i,1) =  ceil(foo(i) / n ); 
    if(out(i,0)==0) {
      out(i,0)=n;
    }
  }
  return(arma::conv_to<arma::umat>::from(out));
}
```

The code seems quite inefficient, but `microbenchmark` reveals that it can be faster than R's `which` function.

Question: Can I further change this function to actually exactly reproduce R's `which` function, i.e. pass `MATRIX == something` to it? Right now I need a second argument for that. I just like to have this for convenience.

---

Update: fixed a bug - needed ceil instead of floor

How to check:

```
ma=floor(abs(rnorm(100,0,6)))
testf=function(k) {all(which(ma==k,arr.ind=T) == whicha(ma,k))} ; sapply(1:10,testf)
```

Benchmark:

```
> microbenchmark(which(ma==k,arr.ind=T) , whicha(ma,k))
Unit: microseconds
                        expr    min     lq median     uq    max neval
 which(ma == k, arr.ind = T) 10.264 11.170 11.774 12.377 51.317   100
               whicha(ma, k)  3.623  4.227  4.830  5.133 36.224   100
```

Comment: Well, a straight up improvement if you want performance is to not copy data around in arma types. Having an `arma::mat` object as input in your `whicha` function means you are copying data from an R object into an armadillo object. This has a cost. Returning an `arma::umat` will convert this object to an R object which also means data copies.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by generating a wrapper R function and doing some ugly work to handle the call. An example, using your code:

```
whicha.cpp
----------

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::umat whicha(arma::mat matrix, int what ){
  arma::uvec outp1;
  int n =   matrix.n_rows;
  outp1 =   find(matrix==what);
  int nf = outp1.n_elem;
  arma::mat out(nf,2);
  arma::vec foo;
  arma::uvec foo2;

  foo = arma::conv_to<arma::vec>::from(outp1) +1;
  out.col(1) = floor(  foo  / n ) +1; 
  foo2 = arma::conv_to<arma::uvec >::from(foo);
  for(int i=0; i<nf; i++){
    out(i,0) =  foo2(i) % n;
  }

  return(arma::conv_to<arma::umat >::from(out));
}

/*** R
whichRcpp <- function(x) {
  call <- match.call()$x
  xx <- eval.parent( call[[2]] )
  what <- eval.parent( call[[3]] )
  return( whicha(xx, what) )
}
x <- matrix(1:1E4, nrow=1E2)
identical( whichRcpp(x == 100L), whicha(x, 100L) ) ## TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark( whichRcpp(x == 100L), whicha(x, 100L) )
*/
```

Unfortunately, `microbenchmark` shows me that parsing the call is a bit slow:

```
Unit: microseconds
                 expr    min     lq median      uq    max neval
 whichRcpp(x == 100L) 43.542 44.143 44.443 45.0440 73.271   100
      whicha(x, 100L) 30.029 30.630 30.930 31.2305 78.075   100
```

It could be worth your time to parse the call at the C level, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I think the additional time between `whicha` and `whichRcpp` is due to the fact that `whichRcpp` evaluates `x == 100L` and therefore creates a temporary logical vector, allocating memory for it, etc ...

Comment: Aren't function arguments evaluated lazily, though? Since we never actually reference `x` in the function call (other than implicitly through `match.call`, it shouldn't be copied. However, navigating calls in R is still slow. If I increase the matrix size (1E6 or 1E7), the difference drops to near zero for me.

That said, your comment above re: arma forcing copies is of course true, and probably costing a lot of time.

Comment: Well, I should take Romain's point serious then. How can I avoid copies and use pointers? The % command only works in integers, so I felt that I need to switch between double and integer within the function.

Comment: More efficient instantiation has been discussed a number of times.  Instantiate an Rcpp matrix first, then use its iterator-alike accessor `begin()` and the size info to create an Armadillo matrix -- see eg `fastLm.cpp` in the RcppArmadillo sources.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code using just Rcpp:

```
src <- '
    using namespace std;

    NumericMatrix X(X_);
    double what = as<double>(what_);
    int n_rows = X.nrow();

    NumericVector rows(0);
    NumericVector cols(0);

    for(int ii = 0; ii < n_rows * n_rows; ii++)
    {
        if(X[ii] == what)
        {
            rows.push_back(ii % n_rows + 1);
            cols.push_back(floor(ii / n_rows) + 1);
        }
    }

    return List::create(rows, cols);
'

fun <- inline:::cxxfunction(signature(X_ = 'numeric', what_ = 'numeric'), src, 'Rcpp')

X <- matrix(1:1E4, nrow=1E2)

rbenchmark:::benchmark(fun(X, 100), which(X == 100L, TRUE), columns = c('test', 'replications', 'elapsed', 'relative'), replications = 1000)

                   test replications elapsed relative
1           fun(X, 100)         1000   0.077    1.000
2 which(X == 100, TRUE)         1000   0.100    1.299

microbenchmark:::microbenchmark(fun(X, 100), which(X == 100L, TRUE), times = 1000L)

                   expr    min      lq  median      uq      max neval
            fun(X, 100) 37.372 41.3780 43.6530 48.4825 1650.154  1000
 which(X == 100L, TRUE) 63.366 64.0745 64.3345 64.8240 1911.858  1000
```

Not much slower compared to the solution from the previous poster. It is interesting that returning a data frame instead of a list decreases the performance significantly.